# Navigation Component - Implicit Deep link causing app multiple instances

Tags: android, deep-linking

I have single activity and multiple fragments using android navigation component. I am using implicit deep link of navigation component. The uri I get from email, when clicked, creates another app instance so the app stack looks like

My app (Instance1)

|

Email app(eg gmail)(clicked on link)

|

My app (Instance2)

What I want is to have single instance and cleared fragment backstack. I have already tried activity launchModes as "singleTop" and "singleInstance". They do keep the single app instance but my deeplink navigation didn't work in that case. Even after clicking the link, app was on top but there was no navigation, I am still seeing the fragment from where I left and not the destination of deeplink.

Comment: “Even after clicking the link, app was on top but there was no navigation, I am still seeing the fragment from where I left and not the destination of deeplink”, I think the way you setup the DeppLink may have problem, could you provide the navigation code?

Comment: What about you test again by removing your app from recent first, and open the link in Email app?